# what regex command i can use in order to create a field in splunk

Tags: splunk-query

I have a data which splunk shows, but i dont see a field for what i wanted

`"ag-somethin-id":["97234d506-E0ASD-4XXX-AXX0-ASD77757"]`

I need to to create a field with **ag-somethin-id** which should actually give me the all the values under those events and it should show something like:

`97234d506-E0ASD-4XXX-AXX0-ASD77757` under this field **ag-somethin-id**

Till now I have tried using the below, but its not correct:

`rex "ag-somethin-id[\\\":]*(?<ag-somethin-id>[^\\[":"]*)"`

Please help in fixing this

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below regex

```
 rex field=_raw "\"ag-somethin-id\":\[\"(?<agsomethinid>[^\"]+)\"\]"
    |rename agsomethinid as "ag-somethin-id"
```

I have verified by executing in regex 101 [Regex for ag-somethin-id](https://regex101.com/r/kswrm8/1/)